# Android : I am using Parse as a backend and I want to save text message on the backend. How to save the text message? help me.

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

**My code for creating image and text message**

protected ParseObject createMessage(){

```
        ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIEN_ID, getRecipientIds());
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, mFileType);

        if(mFileType == "image"){

            byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(this, mMediaUri);

            if(fileBytes == null){
                return null;
            }
            else{//we have an image
                if(mFileType.equals(ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)){
                    //reduce the size of file and it will store it in the file bytes - 10mb is the limit
                    fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);

                }

                String fileName =FileHelper.getFileName(this, mMediaUri, mFileType);
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            message.put("Text File", mTextMessage);

        }

            return message;
        }


protected void send(ParseObject message){
    message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                //successful
                Toast.makeText(RecipientsActivity.this, R.string.success_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{//
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(RecipientsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_message);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title);
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();*/
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**my logcat file**

```
03-17 12:15:20.352: V/Provider/Settings(13895):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-17 12:15:20.356: D/AndroidRuntime(13895): Shutting down VM
03-17 12:15:20.359: W/dalvikvm(13895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4195f9a8)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null.
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:2536)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.turtalabs.bagit.RecipientsActivity.createMessage(RecipientsActivity.java:197)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.turtalabs.bagit.RecipientsActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(RecipientsActivity.java:158)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:995)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:577)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4243)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17520)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
message.put("Text File", mTextMessage);
```

In your code, mTextMessage is not set anywhere, so it is null. The error message says exactly that:

```
...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null. 
03-17 12:15:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(13895): at com.parse.ParseObject.put...
```

Comment: how to set mTextMessage?

Comment: You just need to give mTextMessage a value before you put it on the message object. What is mTextMessage supposed to be? In the code you provided, it is not set. But that also goes for mFileType. So these must be set higher up in the code. mFileType seems to be set, or the code would have given you a nullpointerexception when you test whether it is "image". Where does the text content come from?